# Accessing nested results of an Ansible command result in a list

Tags: json, linux, ansible, nested-lists

After banging my head on my desk for a couple days. Here is where I am.

**The Goal:** Create an entry in the /etc/fstab file using the "UUID=" as my mount point.

> In this case there will be x number of disks on y number of hosts so
>   just putting the information in a vars file unfortunately not
>   possible. Also there will not be any partitions or lvms, for this
>   application we need JBOD with filesystems.

**My Approach:** After some trial and error I have reached a point where my disks are all formatted and they have UUID's. So I am attempting to loop over my devices and then return my UUID to that I can use the mount module to append to the fstab.

**Stuck at:** After getting my list of devices the best way I have discovered to create a list of device UUID's is using the blkid command and registering the results. (see below) My thought was if I could access the nested UUID within 'results2'. Then I could pair the device name/UUID in a new fact for easier access later.

```
#######
#get new facts
#######

- command: "/sbin/blkid -o device"
  register: "result1"

- shell: '/sbin/blkid "{{ item }}" -o value'
  register: "result2"
  with_items: "{{ result1.stdout_lines }}"

#- debug: var="{{ result2.results }}"

- debug: "{{item}}"
  with_together: 
  - "{{result1.stdout_lines}}"
  - "{{result2.results}}"
```

**Output**

```
PLAY [disk-test-node] **********************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [31.212.212.123]

TASK [common : set_fact] *******************************************************
task path: /ansible/roles/common/tasks/main.yml:5
ok: [31.212.212.123] => (item={u'uuid': u'', u'size_total': 8319852544, u'mount': u'/', u'size_available': 7187308544, u'fstype': u'ext4', u'device': u'/dev/xvda1', u'options': u'rw'}) => {"ansible_facts": {"mounted_drives": "/dev/xvda1"}, "changed": false, "item": {"device": "/dev/xvda1", "fstype": "ext4", "mount": "/", "options": "rw", "size_available": 7187308544, "size_total": 8319852544, "uuid": ""}}

TASK [common : command] ********************************************************
task path: /ansible/roles/common/tasks/main.yml:39
changed: [31.212.212.123] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/sbin/blkid", "-o", "device"], "delta": "0:00:00.003729", "end": "2016-11-15 22:11:13.348422", "rc": 0, "start": "2016-11-15 22:11:13.344693", "stderr": "", "stdout": "/dev/xvda1\n/dev/xvdd\n/dev/xvde\n/dev/xvdb\n/dev/xvdc\n/dev/xvdh\n/dev/xvdi\n/dev/xvdf\n/dev/xvdg", "stdout_lines": ["/dev/xvda1", "/dev/xvdd", "/dev/xvde", "/dev/xvdb", "/dev/xvdc", "/dev/xvdh", "/dev/xvdi", "/dev/xvdf", "/dev/xvdg"], "warnings": []}

TASK [common : command] ********************************************************
task path: /ansible/roles/common/tasks/main.yml:42
changed: [31.212.212.123] => (item=/dev/xvda1) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/sbin/blkid \"/dev/xvda1\" -o value", "delta": "0:00:00.002619", "end": "2016-11-15 22:11:15.693323", "item": "/dev/xvda1", "rc": 0, "start": "2016-11-15 22:11:15.690704", "stderr": "", "stdout": "cdbab22a-45d6-4cce-95a3-681f42187a46\next4", "stdout_lines": ["cdbab22a-45d6-4cce-95a3-681f42187a46", "ext4"], "warnings": []}
changed: [31.212.212.123] => (item=/dev/xvdd) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/sbin/blkid \"/dev/xvdd\" -o value", "delta": "0:00:00.002580", "end": "2016-11-15 22:11:17.984917", "item": "/dev/xvdd", "rc": 0, "start": "2016-11-15 22:11:17.982337", "stderr": "", "stdout": "61b23af1-44dd-46c4-8e4b-2af2bd928f98\next4", "stdout_lines": ["61b23af1-44dd-46c4-8e4b-2af2bd928f98", "ext4"], "warnings": []}
```

**Its right there!**
You can see the UUID in "stdout" and "stdout_lines[0]"

**Final Debug Loop after pairing**

```
TASK [common : debug] **********************************************************
task path: /ansible/roles/common/tasks/main.yml:48
ok: [31.212.212.123] => (item=[u'/dev/xvda1', {'_ansible_parsed': True, '_ansible_item_result': True, u'stdout': u'cdbab22a-45d6-4cce-95a3-681f42187a46\next4', '_ansible_no_log': False, u'warnings': [], u'changed': True, u'rc': 0, u'end': u'2016-11-15 22:11:15.693323', u'start': u'2016-11-15 22:11:15.690704', u'cmd': u'/sbin/blkid "/dev/xvda1" -o value', 'item': u'/dev/xvda1', u'delta': u'0:00:00.002619', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'command', u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'/sbin/blkid "/dev/xvda1" -o value', u'removes': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None}}, 'stdout_lines': [u'cdbab22a-45d6-4cce-95a3-681f42187a46', u'ext4'], u'stderr': u''}]) => {
    "<type 'list'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!", 
    "item": [
        "/dev/xvda1", 
        {
            "_ansible_item_result": true, 
            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
            "_ansible_parsed": true, 
            "changed": true, 
            "cmd": "/sbin/blkid \"/dev/xvda1\" -o value", 
            "delta": "0:00:00.002619", 
            "end": "2016-11-15 22:11:15.693323", 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "/sbin/blkid \"/dev/xvda1\" -o value", 
                    "_uses_shell": true, 
                    "chdir": null, 
                    "creates": null, 
                    "executable": null, 
                    "removes": null, 
                    "warn": true
                }, 
                "module_name": "command"
            }, 
            "item": "/dev/xvda1", 
            "rc": 0, 
            "start": "2016-11-15 22:11:15.690704", 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stdout": "cdbab22a-45d6-4cce-95a3-681f42187a46\next4", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "cdbab22a-45d6-4cce-95a3-681f42187a46", 
                "ext4"
            ], 
            "warnings": []
        }
    ]
}
ok: [31.212.212.123] => (item=[u'/dev/xvdd', {'_ansible_parsed': True, '_ansible_item_result': True, u'stdout': u'61b23af1-44dd-46c4-8e4b-2af2bd928f98\next4', '_ansible_no_log': False, u'warnings': [], u'changed': True, u'rc': 0, u'end': u'2016-11-15 22:11:17.984917', u'start': u'2016-11-15 22:11:17.982337', u'cmd': u'/sbin/blkid "/dev/xvdd" -o value', 'item': u'/dev/xvdd', u'delta': u'0:00:00.002580', 'invocation': {'module_name': u'command', u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'/sbin/blkid "/dev/xvdd" -o value', u'removes': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None}}, 'stdout_lines': [u'61b23af1-44dd-46c4-8e4b-2af2bd928f98', u'ext4'], u'stderr': u''}]) => {
    "<type 'list'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!", 
    "item": [
        "/dev/xvdd", 
        {
            "_ansible_item_result": true, 
            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
            "_ansible_parsed": true, 
            "changed": true, 
            "cmd": "/sbin/blkid \"/dev/xvdd\" -o value", 
            "delta": "0:00:00.002580", 
            "end": "2016-11-15 22:11:17.984917", 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "/sbin/blkid \"/dev/xvdd\" -o value", 
                    "_uses_shell": true, 
                    "chdir": null, 
                    "creates": null, 
                    "executable": null, 
                    "removes": null, 
                    "warn": true
                }, 
                "module_name": "command"
            }, 
            "item": "/dev/xvdd", 
            "rc": 0, 
            "start": "2016-11-15 22:11:17.982337", 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stdout": "61b23af1-44dd-46c4-8e4b-2af2bd928f98\next4", 
            "stdout_lines": [
                "61b23af1-44dd-46c4-8e4b-2af2bd928f98", 
                "ext4"
            ], 
            "warnings": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May I advice another solution?

```
- shell: "blkid | sed 's/:.*UUID=\"\\([0-9a-f-]\\+\\).*/ \\1/'"
  register: devs

- debug: msg="dev={{ item.split()[0] }}, uuid={{ item.split()[1] }}"
  with_items: "{{ devs.stdout_lines }}"
```

First task will return `device_name UUID` pairs separated with space.
Second task uses python `split()` function to get `device_name` and `UUID` as separate strings.

Comment: thanks but for me it workrd like this - debug: msg={{ item.stdout_lines }}
  with_items: "{{ devs }}"